# Does $\exp(\sum_i a_i \log(a_i)) = \prod_i a_i^{a_i}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, exponentiation, products

I rewrite here the question to avoid visualization problems.
Does the following hold (for $a_i \in \mathbb R$ and $a_i>0$)?

$$e^{\sum_i a_i \log(a_i)}=\prod_i a_i^{a_i}$$

Comment: You need the $a_i>0$ for the left hand side to make sense.

Comment: Thanks @JpMcCarthy, I'll add it to the question text!

Comment: If $\log()$ means $\ln()$ i.e. $\log_e()$ then it is true, else not.

Comment: I don't see any reason why it should not. Isn't it just a plain expression simplification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up what was written in the comments, assuming $a_i>0,\,\forall i$, $$\begin{align}\exp\left(\sum_ia_i\log_b(a_i)\right)&=\exp(a_1\log_b(a_1)+a_2\log_b(a_2)\cdots)\\&=\exp(a_1\log_b a_1)\times\exp(a_2\log_b a_2)\times\cdots\\&=\prod_i\exp(a_i\log_b a_i)\\&=\prod_i \exp\left(a_i\cdot\frac{\ln a_i}{\ln b}\right)\\&=\prod_i {a_i}^{a_i/(\ln b)}\end{align}$$
So this only equals to $\prod_i {a_i}^{a_i}$ if $\ln b=1\iff b=e$.